# How do I recreate a VIEW as a local table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and have access to a bunch of views without the original tables that the view depends on. I have copied some data from this view into a file and would like to import it into a database that I locally created to do some analysis.

The brute-force way of doing this is to manually write down the `CREATE TABLE` statement looking at the columns in the view but is there a better way to get the `CREATE` or `CREATE VIEW` statement that I can directly use to recreate a similar table in my `localhost`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Create a linked server](http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/how-to-add-a-linked-server/) in your localhost to this server. Then use (while connected to localhost)

```
SELECT * INTO NewTableName FROM LinkedServer.DBName.SchemaName.View
```

and a new table in your current DB in localhost would be created.

Comment: +1 Thank you. I'm afraid I'll have to re-import the data and cannot create a linked server due to security issues.

Comment: @Legend, if you can connect to the server, you can create the linked server as well. If you don't want to leave the linked server permanently, drop it after importing the data. Creating and dropping can be done using a series of SQL commands instead of UI.

Comment: @Legend, other option would be to use [Import Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx).

Comment: I think it would depend on whether the OP needs to do this periodically as with linked servers it's very easy to run into a double hop security scenario, particularly in SQL tasks of SQL agent jobs...

Answer (score 1):

What I typically prefer to do is use SSIS for data transforms. The first step in the package would be to grab the definition using a `SELECT INTO ... WHERE 1=0` so that it doesn't bring over any data and minimizes the locking time (`SELECT INTO`'s result in database wide locks). Then once you have the resulting table with the source view's definition, then copy the data over.

If you're afraid the view's definition can change, stick with an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM` SQL task. Otherwise, save the definition that you retrieved from the SQL above and create the table (if it does not already exist). Then use a data flow task to transfer the data over.

With either of these approaches, you avoid the potential double hop scenario (if you're using Windows authentication). It's also reusable in a SQL agent job if you need to do this periodically. Otherwise, it may be a little overkill.

Or you can just run the first part in SSMS but I definitely recommend using the `WHERE 1=0` then using an `INSERT INTO` rather than a straight `SELECT INTO`. Again, to minimize database locking.